# Run a bat EXE to a bat Java

Tags: batch-file

I am trying to make a batch file to start a batch file, but I fail. :(

```
start test.bat
```

When I make the file bat file into an EXE file it won't start the `test.bat`

Here are the command lines inside `test.bat`.

```
@echo off
javaw -XX:HeapDumpPath=MojangTricksIntelDriversForPerformance_javaw.exe_minecraft.exe.heapdump -Xmx1024M -Dfml.ignoreInvalidMinecraftCertificates=true -Dfml.ignorePatchDiscrepancies=true -Djava.library.path="versions\Zer0Craft\Zer0Craft_TagCraftMC" -cp "libraries\net\minecraftforge\\forge\1.7.10-10.13.4.1614-1.7.10\forge-1.7.10-10.13.4.1614-1.7.10.jar";"libraries\net\minecraft\\launchwrapper\1.12\launchwrapper-1.12.jar";"libraries\org\ow2\asm\\asm-all\5.0.3\asm-all-5.0.3.jar";"libraries\com\typesafe\akka\\akka-actor_2.11\2.3.3\akka-actor_2.11-2.3.3.jar";"libraries\com\typesafe\\config\1.2.1\config-1.2.1.jar";"libraries\org\scala-lang\\scala-actors-migration_2.11\1.1.0\scala-actors-migration_2.11-1.1.0.jar";"libraries\org\scala-lang\\scala-compiler\2.11.1\scala-compiler-2.11.1.jar";"libraries\org\scala-lang\plugins\\scala-continuations-library_2.11\1.0.2\scala-continuations-library_2.11-1.0.2.jar";"libraries\org\scala-lang\plugins\\scala-continuations-plugin_2.11.1\1.0.2\scala-continuations-plugin_2.11.1-1.0.2.jar";"libraries\org\scala-lang\\scala-library\2.11.1\scala-library-2.11.1.jar";"libraries\org\scala-lang\\scala-parser-combinators_2.11\1.0.1\scala-parser-combinators_2.11-1.0.1.jar";"libraries\org\scala-lang\\scala-reflect\2.11.1\scala-reflect-2.11.1.jar";"libraries\org\scala-lang\\scala-swing_2.11\1.0.1\scala-swing_2.11-1.0.1.jar";"libraries\org\scala-lang\\scala-xml_2.11\1.0.2\scala-xml_2.11-1.0.2.jar";"libraries\lzma\\lzma\0.0.1\lzma-0.0.1.jar";"libraries\com\google\guava\\guava\17.0\guava-17.0.jar";"libraries\com\mojang\\netty\1.6\netty-1.6.jar";"libraries\com\mojang\\realms\1.3.5\realms-1.3.5.jar";"libraries\org\apache\commons\\commons-compress\1.8.1\commons-compress-1.8.1.jar";"libraries\org\apache\httpcomponents\\httpclient\4.3.3\httpclient-4.3.3.jar";"libraries\commons-logging\\commons-logging\1.1.3\commons-logging-1.1.3.jar";"libraries\org\apache\httpcomponents\\httpcore\4.3.2\httpcore-4.3.2.jar";"libraries\java3d\\vecmath\1.3.1\vecmath-1.3.1.jar";"libraries\net\sf\trove4j\\trove4j\3.0.3\trove4j-3.0.3.jar";"libraries\com\ibm\icu\\icu4j-core-mojang\51.2\icu4j-core-mojang-51.2.jar";"libraries\net\sf\jopt-simple\\jopt-simple\4.5\jopt-simple-4.5.jar";"libraries\com\paulscode\\codecjorbis\20101023\codecjorbis-20101023.jar";"libraries\com\paulscode\\codecwav\20101023\codecwav-20101023.jar";"libraries\com\paulscode\\libraryjavasound\20101123\libraryjavasound-20101123.jar";"libraries\com\paulscode\\librarylwjglopenal\20100824\librarylwjglopenal-20100824.jar";"libraries\com\paulscode\\soundsystem\20120107\soundsystem-20120107.jar";"libraries\io\netty\\netty-all\4.0.10.Final\netty-all-4.0.10.Final.jar";"libraries\com\google\guava\\guava\15.0\guava-15.0.jar";"libraries\org\apache\commons\\commons-lang3\3.1\commons-lang3-3.1.jar";"libraries\commons-io\\commons-io\2.4\commons-io-2.4.jar";"libraries\commons-codec\\commons-codec\1.9\commons-codec-1.9.jar";"libraries\net\java\jinput\\jinput\2.0.5\jinput-2.0.5.jar";"libraries\net\java\jutils\\jutils\1.0.0\jutils-1.0.0.jar";"libraries\com\google\code\gson\\gson\2.2.4\gson-2.2.4.jar";"libraries\com\mojang\\authlib\1.5.21\authlib-1.5.21.jar";"libraries\org\apache\logging\log4j\\log4j-api\2.0-beta9\log4j-api-2.0-beta9.jar";"libraries\org\apache\logging\log4j\\log4j-core\2.0-beta9\log4j-core-2.0-beta9.jar";"libraries\org\lwjgl\lwjgl\\lwjgl\2.9.1\lwjgl-2.9.1.jar";"libraries\org\lwjgl\lwjgl\\lwjgl_util\2.9.1\lwjgl_util-2.9.1.jar";"libraries\org\lwjgl\lwjgl\\lwjgl-platform\2.9.1\lwjgl-platform-2.9.1-natives-windows.jar";"libraries\net\java\jinput\\jinput-platform\2.0.5\jinput-platform-2.0.5-natives-windows.jar";"libraries\tv\twitch\\twitch\5.16\twitch-5.16.jar";"libraries\tv\twitch\\twitch-platform\5.16\twitch-platform-5.16-natives-windows-32.jar";"libraries\tv\twitch\\twitch-external-platform\4.5\twitch-external-platform-4.5-natives-windows-32.jar";"versions\Zer0Craft\Zer0Craft.jar" net.minecraft.launchwrapper.Launch --username Steve --version Zer0Craft --assetsDir "assets" --assetIndex 1.7.10 --uuid 8667ba71b85a4004af54457a9734eed7 --accessToken OFFLINE_MODE --userProperties {} --userType ${user_type} --tweakClass cpw.mods.fml.common.launcher.FMLTweaker
```

Answer (score 0):

How do you mean "make a batch file to start a batch file"? You're wanting to have a batch file that RUNS another batch file?!

Not only is that somewhat time consuming, it's not very efficient either.

If you're wanting to run another batch file, you simply add this line to your original batch file:

```
call batchfilenamegoeshere.bat
```

Second of all. How do you intend on turning your .batch file into a .exe? You should give us some context on how you went around doing that.